# Row Headings won't repeat on new pages

Tags: reporting-services, repeat, reportbuilder3.0, rowheader

I have, what I think is a pretty simple table in Report Builder 3.0.  I have team & salesperson grouped by team in the far left column (row headers) and I want those to repeat when the report is multiple pages.  I've tried what this article suggests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045.aspx but it doesn't seem to work.  I have a sales amount and a goal in the table with various departments grouped in my headers.

How do I get the row headers to repeat?

Comment: Refer this links if helpful: http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/10/ssrs-repeat-header-using-tablixtable.html  and http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/10/ssrs-repeat-tablix-header-on-page-scroll.html

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried both of those.  Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the property values of the corresponding static rows(header related)..to do this you can click on the arrow pointed downwards in the bottom right..select the "Advanced  mode"  which opens the strows..select the corrsponding static header row under "Row Groups" in bottom left of report builder..Check if the "RepeatOnNewPAge" to true and "Keep With group" to After..Change the values if they are not ..You can go through the following link

http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/06/14/what-to-do-when-the-repeatcolumnheaders-property-in-a-tablix-isn-t-working.aspx